# Why doesn't the time of the date object change?How can I make it change?

Tags: javascript

```
> var a = new Date();
< undefined
> a.getTime();
< 1459524198042
> a.getTime();
< 1459524198042
```

This is the javascript console.
I want a variable that will have the time changed with time ... I make another prompt and then I can tell the difference between the two .

In short, I want to create a timer using the `Date()` object. Is it possible? If not then what else can I use?

Is it really possible to make the data of variable, variable?

Comment: `new Date` is a timestamp, it is not magically updated. When you want to get the current time you'd create another date object.

Comment: @elclanrs oh ok. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

You get the current time with

```
Date.now();
```

You could create your own object:

```
var myNow = {
  get time() { return Date.now(); }
};
console.log(myNow.time);
```

(ES2015 syntax)

Date instances are "frozen" at a particular point in time; they don't update.

Comment: Well, they are "frozen" unless you modify them (`setHours()`, `setMinutes()`, `setSeconds()`, etc.)

Comment: Well yes, clearly. They can be changed, but they don't change themselves.